# Why isn't this method recognised by the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, nameerror

I'm trying to write a program that simulates a fight between a monster and a hero using OOP and part of that is generating stats for the monster, including element type, defence, attack and name, but when I call GetMonsterElement(self, Melement), I get

> NAMEERROR line 9, 'GetMonsterElement' is not defined

I've attached some code below and I would ve very grateful if someone could explain what I've done wrong.

```
 import random, time

 class monster:
     def __init__(self):
        self.Melement = self.GenerateMonsterElement(self, Melement)
        self.name = ''
        self.hp = 0
        self.attack = 0
        self.defence = 0
        DisplayMonsterElement(self, Melement)

     def GenerateMonsterElement(self, Melement):
        ElementGen = random.randint(1,3)
        if ElementGen == 1:
           self.Melement = 'Ice'
        elif ElementGen == 2:
           self.Melement = 'Fire'
        elif ElementGen == 3:
           self.Melement = 'Grass'
        return self.Melement

    def DisplayMonsterElement(self, Melement):
       print(self.Melement)

def main():
   ThisBattle = monster()
   monster.Run()

main()
```

Comment: If you're trying to call `GenerateMonsterElement` as an instance method inside `monster` (and assuming it is actually declared that way), the syntax is `self.GenerateMonsterElement()`.

Comment: I havn't gotten much further than this as I'm just a student trying to learn to program, so at the moment I'm just testing to see if I can give the monster and element and return it. below that I have ThisBattle = Monster() and monster.run()

Comment: Can you update the question above with the correct code? The snippet of `monster` conflicts with everything else you say about it: Is it `monster` or `Monster`? Is it `GetMonsterElement` or `GenerateMonsterElement`?

Comment: These are instance methods so should be called by preceeding them with `self.`

Comment: Your code neither calls nor defines ``GetMonsterElement``. Why do you expect to be able to call it? Where do you call it?

Comment: I've imported all the code which I have completed so far, All i want it to do is generate Ice, fire or grass at this point in time and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant to write this:

```
import random, time

class monster:
     def __init__(self):
        self.Melement = self.GenerateMonsterElement()
        self.name = ''
        self.hp = 0
        self.attack = 0
        self.defence = 0
        self.DisplayMonsterElement()

     def GenerateMonsterElement(self):
        ElementGen = random.randint(1, 3)
        elements = {1:'Ice', 2:'Fire', 3:'Grass'}
        return elements[ElementGen]

     def DisplayMonsterElement(self):
        print(self.Melement)

def main():
   ThisBattle = monster()
   #monster.Run()

main()
```

You can use a `dict` to select `Melement` instead of `if .. elif ..`

I've tidied up the calls and declarations of methods.

There is no `monster.Run()` yet.